# What is the best Anti-Pollution Mask?

Tags: safety, urban-riding, pollution

I bike everyday in Paris and I am looking for a mask with a particulates filter.

Comment: Related: [Is pollution a problem in urban cycling?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/2170/8)

Comment: Despite the previous question on this, can anyone recommend a mask appropriate for cycling?

Comment: Slightly off topic - but is there any reason to believe a mask you can actually breathe through will stop pm10 or pm2.5 particles?

Comment: My experience with industrial safety masks is that if it has a tight enough filter to protect you, it will also be a chore to breath through.

Comment: @mgb http://aqicn.org/mask/ is just one example of particulate protection mask. Please get educated. While particles are smaller than they holes, they are attracted to the fibers and as they go through the mask, they get stuck.

Answer (score 6):

Today, the major part of city masks were made to avoid breathing dust as @mgb said, you need more than a simple mask to stop micro particles. Anyway try http://www.u2sportmask.com/ (for example).

Comment: there are efficient mask with integrated particles fitlers - read here for more details: http://www.edie.net/Library/view_article.asp?id=4051&channel=0

Comment: The link title says "masking out smog" - no filter will stop smog, it's a chemical mix of NOx, O3 and a few sulfides/sulfates. The only thing that would stop smog is an O2 supply.

Comment: @mgb That's actually plain wrong. Smog originally referred to sooth particulate matter from coal burning, and that can definitely be caught with masks.